# How to show and hide two different divs with javascript?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I tried to use some javascript I found on this site to show and hide two different divs. Basically, when someone clicks on the arrives or clicks on "a button", then I want the AAA div to show up below. When someone clicks the "b button", I want to hide the AAA div and show the BBB div below.

I thought about using Bootstrap collapse, but didn't want the animation.

What am I doing wrong?

http://matthewtbrown.com/test/index.html

```
// set content on click
$('.button').click(function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
setContent($(this));
});

// set content on load
$('.button.active').length && setContent($('.button.active'));

function setContent($el) {
 $('.button').removeClass('active');
$('.container').hide();

$el.addClass('active');
$($el.data('rel')).show();
}

<div class="flr-wrap">
<ul>
    <li><a class="timebutton active" data-rel="#content-a" href="#">a button</a></li>
    <li><a class="timebutton" data-rel="#content-b" href="#">b button</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="flr-inner">
    <div class="timecontainer" id="content-a">
        AAA
    </div>
    <div class="timecontainer" id="content-b">
        BBB
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `What am I doing wrong?` well, for a start, you're not posting any code in the question itself

Comment: any errors in the browser developer tools console ... like `ReferenceError: $ is not defined` for example?

Comment: loading `jQuery 3.1.0` AND `1.11.3` looks wrong too ... but also, loading `js/timeentries.js` - which relies on jquery - before loading jquery is probably the biggest error in your page

Comment: no need for code now - the problem is the order in which you are loading your javascript ... and loading two vastly different versions of jQuery will only end in tears

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have jQuery loaded you can just use click handlers and the show() hide() functions.

```
$(".a-button").click(() => {
  $("#foo").hide()
  $("#bar").show()
});

$(".b-button").click(() => {
  $("#bar").hide()
  $("#foo").show()
});
```